# Custom field in order not shown on checkout panel

Tags: commerce

I just discovered the commerce 2 module.
I create a date field in the order type ( each customer need to select a shipping date when they bought product ).
If  I create the order from the adminstrator interface the field is displayed.
But when the customer use cart to buy a product the date field is not display ?
Can you help ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no code that shows custom order fields at checkout. You will need to write a [custom checkout pane plugin](https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/checkout/create-custom-checkout-pane).